# Does the STS103-734-73 NASA picture show another spacecraft?

Tags: photography, space-flight, nasa, ufo

[UFO News](http://yufonews.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/ufo-seen-during-repair-hubble-telescope.html) reported in July 2014 that an older image taken of the Hubble Telescope is on a spacecraft (a "craft").

> The image was taken in December 1999,, on STS-103, a repair mission on which Space Shuttle Discovery flew to the highest-ever orbit in the Shuttle program’s history - and a painstaking frame-by-frame analysis has uncovered a clear image of a craft in NASA's official images.

The following [pictures from NASA](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/photo.pl?mission=STS103&roll=734&frame=73) shows something on the right hand side.

#### Frame 70 (nothing there yet) (23:03:48)

(Except for these pixels in previous [frame 68](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/photo.pl?mission=STS103&roll=734&frame=68) [image: NASA STS103-734-68 - engine flames]?)

[image: NASA Photo STS103-734-70]

#### Frame 71 (some brighter pixels show up) (23:03:53)

[image: NASA Photo STS103-734-71 - lights]

[image: NASA Photo STS103-734-71]

#### Frames 72-74 (more bright pixels on the right side) (23:03:56)

[image: NASA Photo STS103-734-73]

#### Frame 75 (the pixels become dark again) (23:04:02)

[image: NASA Photo STS103-734-75]

Do these images show another craft?

Comment: It will be easy to reformulate this question: *a painstaking frame-by-frame analysis* Who has done this analysis ? Where are is been published ? Then you get the "notable claim" that can be discussed...

Comment: @kenorb Yes of course those **reflections in the window** are of a spacecraft: either the approaching space shuttle itself or of the Hubble (yes, they are both spacecraft). I am more curious as to how you can think the upper right reflection is of particular importance while the one in the lower right one is entirely ignored and not worthy of any attention.